# Replacing img src attributes from a file containing the names of the images using Python

Tags: python

I have to create a webpage for a team which consists of over 30 people. This webpage will consist of a picture followed by the name of the person in the picture. I have 30 such image files.

I wrote a python script to save the source of the image in a text file. For example,
My directory contains the pictures of the team in 30 jpeg/png/jpg files and my script ran through the directory and saved the names in a file called 'names.txt' as follows:

```
abhijeet.jpg
amit pic.jpg
anjani.jpeg
anusha.jpg
bharath.jpg
chandrakanth.jpg and so on
```

I was trying to find out a way by which I could replace the attributes of the image with the image names in the file. I tried running the following piece of code but it didnt return anything.The piece of code is as follows :

```
import lxml.html as LH
root = LH.fromstring(html_string)
with open('ccd_pics/names.txt','r')  as f:
    result = [line.split() for line in f]
i=0
for el in root.iter('img'):
    el.attrib['src'] = '"' + result[i] + '"'
    i+=1
print(LH.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
```

The following is the section of HTML code that is repeated over 30 times and whose img src has to be replaced :

```
 <div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col mdl-cell--3-col-tablet ">
            <figure class="mdl-card__media">
                    <img src="ccd_pics/amit pic.jpg"/>
            </figure>
            <div class="mdl-card__title">
                <h1 class="mdl-card__title-text">Amit</h1>
             </div>
        </div>
```

I have a fair knowledge of python,css and javascript.
Do note that my boss wants me to implement this card layout for some cynical reason of his/her own and I have no other option left.

**UPDATE**: Solved this by looping through the html file and saving its content to a string which I then passed into the function `LH.fromstring()`. 
The question can be closed now

Comment: Why are you trying to replace anything? Just generate a new HTML file using a template string.

Comment: Can we continue over chat about this?

Comment: ok. don't know how to start a chat here

Comment: I guess only moderators can do that. Can you help me out with it here?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. `names.txt` is right in your code. Have you tried running the code?

Comment: Yes I have, and nothing seems to happen